# How can I get "ViewBag" value from Controller to js file after Ajax response

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have initialized ViewBag value in a Action method and same value I want to get before Ajax call when I am going to call another Action Method in my js file. Please help.

Comment: Please include some sample code so we may be able to help.

Comment: call it from your view as `@ViewBag.SomeVar` or from javascript as `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.SomeVar)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand but I think you'll need to store those value somewhere on the client side. In a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="someVar" value="@ViewBag.SomeVar" />
```

or a javascript variable

```
var someVar = @ViewBag.SomeVar;
```

There are other ways like cookies or sessions but these probably aren't what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, after assigning value in ViewBag, no any page is being  render. I am setting value in (in ViewBag) controller calling a ajax call and same value I want to get before when I am going to make another ajax call from my js file.